# Why doesnt PyJwt recognize the positional argument "algorithm" when using "ES256" signing method?

Tags: python, django, pyjwt

I'm using PyJwt to generate and encode a JWT for apple application notification service token authentication which requires the `ES256` signing algorithm as noted [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns) .

```
self.server = settings.APNS_SERVER
self.algorithm = 'ES256'
PRIVATE_KEY = settings.APNS_PRIVATE_KEY

encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(
    {'iss': settings.TEAM_ID, 'iat': time.time()},
    PRIVATE_KEY,
    algorithm=self.algorithm,
    headers={'alg': self.algorithm, 'kid': settings.APNS_KEY_ID},
)
```

When passed this way, I get the following error:

```
     encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 63, in encode
     return api_jws.encode(json_payload, key, algorithm, headers, json_encoder)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 114, in encode
     signature = alg_obj.sign(signing_input, key)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py", line 423, in sign
     der_sig = key.sign(msg, ec.ECDSA(self.hash_alg()))
 TypeError: sign() missing 1 required positional argument: 'algorithm'
```

This doesn't happen when I use the `RS256` or `HS256` signing algorithm.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What's the type of `PRIVATE_KEY`? Seems the .sign() method is getting called on it.

Comment: ah - just looked. its an RSA private key. that would explain it, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your private key is not correctly generated. Use this instruction to generate ES256 key: https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/openssl-key-generation